# switch function not working in matlab callback function

Tags: matlab, callback

I created a simple GUI with matlab Guide and want to use a simple switch function in one of the callback functions.

The function looks as follows:

```
ret = 0;
switch intervall
    case 1
        ret = 0.82;
    case 5
        ret = 0.82;
    case 10
        ret = 0.78;
    case 15
        ret = 0.78;
    case 30
        ret = 0.78;
    case 60
        ret = 0.82;
end
```

the variable "intervall" is a string and is retrieved from user input. However, when I run the code the switch function never seems to execute and the "ret" variable remains unchanged from the initial value of 0. 
I have executed this code separately in a script and it worked perfectly...

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Update problems are current with GUI. Can you please post the entire code of the `.m` file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `intervall` is a string, your `case` arguments should be strings to.
For example:

```
ret = 0;
switch intervall
    case '1'
        ret = 0.82;
    case '5'
        ret = 0.82;
    case '10'
        ret = 0.78;
    case '15'
        ret = 0.78;
    case '30'
        ret = 0.78;
    case '60'
        ret = 0.82;
end
```

Comment: I have tried this before, but it still does not work. I also tried converting intervall to a number before and then use the code as posted above, but still no result. I think it must have to do something with the variable hierarchy or something like that... As I said, in a separate script, this worked like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem and it was not related to the switch function. The intervall value is retrieved from a popup menu and somehow they weren't extracted correctly. The function works now, thank you anyway for your help!

Comment: You should should tag this question as "Solved", so that the community knows there is one less problem in the stack.